# What is the maximum likelihood estimate of p?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, nonparametric

$\{1,2,3,3,4\}$ is a random sample from $X$ that has the following probability distribution:
$$
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=1)=P(X=2)=\tfrac{1}{4} \\
& \Pr(X=3)=p  \\
& \Pr(X=4)=\tfrac{1}{2}-p 
\end{align} 
$$

Find the Maximum likelihood estimate for $p$.

I have solved many problems on finding MLE's and I know only the method of finding the likelihood function and differentiating it. I have no clue how to solve this one.

Comment: What makes you think that your usual method won't work? Did you try writing down the likelihood?

Comment: I was not able to write down the likelihood function

Comment: To write it down, start by noting the distribution is a sample of IID categorical random variables. Then substitute in the facts given.

Comment: @idpd15 Can you calculate the value of the likelihood at (say) $p=0.4$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the observations are IID, the likelihood function of $p$ factors as:

$$\mathcal{L}(p) = \prod_{i=1}^5 Pr(X=x_i\,|\,p) = \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} \times p \times p \times \left( \frac{1}{2} - p \right) $$

You can then differentiate and solve for $p$, which gives you the value $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: This is the right answer.  You can note that since X=1 and X=2 really don't provide any information about p, they samples equaling 1 or 2 can be ignored. The probability of 3 and 4 sum to 1/2. So since 3 occurs twice as often as 4, p(X=3) should be twice P(X=4) meaning p(X=3) =1/3 and p(X=4)=1/6 to maximize the likelihood.